# Netty HttpClient - response timeout vs. read timeout

Tags: netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

`HttpClient` from offers various "timeouts" to be configured, two slightly confuses me:

- responseTimeout: `This is time that takes to receive a response after sending a request`
- ReadTimeoutHandler: `Raises a ReadTimeoutException when no data was read within a certain period of time`

**Could someone please explain the key difference between them?**

---

Generic scenario - make a call using spring reactive `WebClient`, that uses `HttpClient` under the hood:

1. establish connection to remote server *>>> here we leverage `ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS`*
2. TLS handshake *>>> here we leverage `ReadTimeoutHandler` as I am correct?*
3. Send request
4. ...wait...
5. Receive response *>>> which "timeout" takes precedence here: response/read?*

Answer (score 3):

If you use WebFlux and Netty, the `httpClient` should be the Netty `httpClient`. Did you have a look there? https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html

1. Connect timeOut -> this is correct, if you can't connect to the
   remote server for any reason, this timeOut will be used.
2. TLS handshake, check: `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient#secure(`):
   If not configured otherwise, Netty will assume 10 seconds timeout
   for the handshake. If you want to define another timeout, use
   `reactor.netty.tcp.sslHandshakeTimeout` https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html#secure--
3. The connection is now established and you send your request. By
   using `ReadTimeoutHandler` you can define how long to wait until you
   receive data over the connection. This could be for example the
   whole response in one go, or bytes if the responses is streamed. `responseTimeout` in `httpClient` does the same. Both create the `TcpClient` with the given `timeOut` setting. The benefit of ReadTimeoutHandler is that you get a callback that executes logic you defined when the timeout occurs.

Comment: [2] as I use `.secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(...)`, I see that there is only `.handshakeTimeout(..)` which, tbh is now even more confusing... looking on https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1159 - my understanding was that, it is `ReadTimeoutHandler` that is responsible for hand-shake timeout hmm; could you elaborate here please?

Comment: [3] I am using 
`tcpClient.doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                    .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))`
by saying *callback* - did you mean an option to create custom `ReadTimeoutHandler` instead?

Comment: I won't recommend using ReadTimeoutHandler and the reasons are in https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1159

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva can you please explain this?
_They apply even when an HTTP request is not being processed. For example, they could cause a connection sitting in the connection pool to be closed, even though it might be able to be used a split-second later by another request_

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in comment from @violeta-georgieva > [Netty HttpClient - response timeout vs. read timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179173/netty-httpclient-response-timeout-vs-read-timeout#comment113504510_64182367) the "`responseTimeout`" should be used.